# Spring Autowired Component is null in bean method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use an `@Autowired` variable in an `@Configuration` class, where a bean is created using `@Bean` in a method. However the component I need to create the bean with is `null`.

```
@Autowired
private JDAListener listener;

@Bean
public ShardManager shardManager() throws LoginException, IllegalArgumentException {
    DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = DefaultShardManagerBuilder.createDefault(this.botToken)
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
            .setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE)
            .setShardsTotal(this.totalShards)
            .addEventListeners(Arrays.asList(this.listener)); //throws Exception

    return builder.build();
}
```

The Exception I get is as follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'config': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'shardManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'shardManager' defined in class path resource [dev/teamnight/nightbot/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [net.dv8tion.jda.api.sharding.ShardManager]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'config' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'shardManager' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listeners may not be null
```

Comment: Remove the `@Autowired` field and use the `shardManager(JDAListener listener)` as a method signature instead. You are probably both creating the bean and injecting it from the same config (or config that is being used).

Comment: Circular reference involving containing bean 'config'. need to change your dependency reference.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the code snippet is a part of some kind of configuration (Something annotated with `@Configuration` or maybe even `@SpringBootApplication`).

In this case:

1. Make `JDAListener` be managed by Spring container as well.
2. Inject the instance of `JDAListener` bean into the shard manager by passing the parameter to the `shardManager` method

You will end up with the code that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {


  @Bean // now jda listener is managed by spring!
  public JDAListener jdaListener() {
     return new JDAListener();
  }

  @Bean // note the parameter to the method
  public ShardManager shardManager(JDAListener jdaListener) throws LoginException, IllegalArgumentException {
        DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = 
              DefaultShardManagerBuilder.createDefault(this.botToken)
                 .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                 .setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE)
                 .setShardsTotal(this.totalShards)
                 .addEventListeners(Arrays.asList(jdaListener)); //throws Exception

    return builder.build();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're facing this issue because Spring attempted to dependency inject the bean before it injected the listener. How about you try declare JdaListener as a bean as well?

Answer (score 0):

Is JDAListener is marked as @Component/ @Service or something which tells the framework that it is suppose to be treated as a bean? Also, quickly check your component scan configuration.